# How to get the HWND of the main window in wine

Tags: c++, linux, x11, wine

If we run the command: wine program.exe , does wine save the hwnd of the main window for the program.exe ? And how to get it ?
For example if I want to printf in wine logs ,the hwnd of the main window of program.exe , is this hwnd saved somewhere in a wine internal funciton?

Comment: Get it from where? And what would you do with it? Wine implements Win32, so `GetForegroundWindow` works _within_ Wine.

Comment: Are you asking if wine saves the HWND in a text file somewhere? "does wine save the hwnd of the main window for the program.exe" is very ambiguous.

Comment: I'm modifying wine source code . I do not need to get it from window exe .Just to get it from wine internal functions  , if wine keeps it somewhere

Comment: @sashoalm , I dnt expect wine to save it to a file .Just in memory.

Comment: @MariaGheorghe Why not call GetForegroundWindow() from a Wine internal function? I think Wine can call its own API as well.